# Event on didSelctItemAtIndexPath when this is into header - iOS

Tags: iphone, events, ios6, header, collectionview

I was building a app on iOS, and in a collectionView I have a header, and needs create event "touch up inside" for this header, like i 've create in the others cells of the collectioView

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thx a lot, I hope u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy..
I'm create a simple button and edit in tag attributes -> type -> custom... the button now it's transparent and add a function in event ***touch up inside***.. :D